How do stop Include suggestion for Complex Properties
I've the below sample application using an Complex Property in EF Core. When querying the Customer DbSet, Rider gives me an false-positive suggestion to include the Address property.

However, when trying to include Address as suggested, that gives an run-time exception:

The expression 'customer.Address' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Why is this suggesting there and how can I get rid of it? Is that an bug or issue inside Rider?
I know that I can insert an disable comment above the line to disable the suggestion or add it to an editorconfig etc. but I'm trying to solve the issue instead.
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

await using var context = new AppDbContext();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();

var customers = await context.Customers
    .ToListAsync();

var customerQueryInMemory = customers
    .Where(c => c.Address.Street == "123 Main St")
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(customerQueryInMemory.Count);

internal class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("CONNECTION_STRING");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .ComplexProperty(c => c.Address);
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}


What's the actual code you used? You wouldn't get The expression 'customer.Address' from context.Customers.Include(c=>c.Address)

Which Rider version are you using? Newer Rider versions may have fixed this. You can't fix an analyzer bug with settings, only silence it. I you check YouTrack you'll find related issues that have been fixed in one version or another

I'm using newest versions of Rider. The actual code is the sample I have already provided.
As mentioned, if I include the address as the suggestion recommends, the codes does not work -- I get the exception that I provided as well.

The latest is 2024.3 EAP 5. If the problem remains in that version, create a bug report at YouTrack. I already posted a link that shows there have been false positives in the past, that were fixed. There's nothing similar to what you posted so I suspect JetBrains isn't aware of the bug yet. Only JetBrains can fix bugs in their analyzer. The only thing you can do is silence the warning or ignore it

The actual code is the sample where's the Include call? Where's the code that threw The expression 'customer.Address' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation...... ?

Try marking the Address class with the [ComplexType] attribute. Rider might pick up on that and recognize the class isn't a vanilla navigation property. It's not going to resolve ComplexProperty(...) from the EF explicit configuration.

That looks like a bug. I submitted this issue: RSRP-499275 False "Query can return incomplete data for related entities"
